# Who is the woman in the opening cutscene of Tales of the Abyss 3DS version?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss

In the [opening of Tales of the Abyss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHHBP7KARa4&t=1m40s) (from the 3DS, not sure about the PS2), at around 1:40, there's a shot of the Daarth Cathedral where there's a woman letting out something like a gust from behind her (moment before you see Ion or Florian at the alter behind). There seems to be more of this woman, as when I start a new game, the first cutscene shows a group of them gathering above the planet.

I'm currently on the final battle. At first, I thought the woman was Lorelei, but the characters call Lorelei a he. I checked the walkthrough to see if I was on the very last battle, since in *Tales of Graces F* there was a second story after I defeated Lambda which focused on fighting Little Queen, I confirmed that the fights I'm on are the last. (Then again, the walkthrough is for the PS2 version. A second story could have been added for the 3DS version, but I doubt it.)

Since I'm at the endgame, I am still wondering who this woman is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it the spirit of [Yulia Jue](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Yulia_Jue). It's also her her spirit floating about the world in the opening scene.

[image: Yulia Jue]